# removing the elements in the array with certain properties and sort

Tags: c++, algorithm

There was one two dimensonal array used in my office application

for eg `int arr[10][4];`

say suppose the  first index represents fruits and seconds index represent the properties of fruit like price,colour`etc.

so i can store 10 fruits with 4 properties for each fruit.

say suppose my task is to remove the entries in array whose fruit colour is red.

To achieve this i just looped through the array and made the entries of apple to zero.

for eg if apple was at 4th index, then `arr[4][0]=0;`

like wise i made the matched criterion to zero

and to  remove the entry of apple in array 
with looping i moved the entries with 0 at arr[x][0] to down of the array.(bubble sort)

but the above method is not seems to be good programming practice,

let me know your thoughts

Note: I cannot change the data structure because it is used at many parts of my application

Comment: I'd probably make a struct/class to represent a fruit - using another array to represent properties is weird to me. Then use one of the STL containers (`vectors`) instead of arrays, along with `algorithms` (`remove_if`)

Comment: @Ben I totally second your comment; the described approach seems to be a rather unsuitable way of representing the data, especially as the dimensions of the array cannot be changed. Do you have full access to the source code?

Comment: I think the larger problem is that the design itself doesn't stem from good programming practice, there's not much room for improvement if you can't steer away from misusing data structures in the first place.